# Implementing A* for maze solving

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I have a project for school.

I have to read from a file a maze that is formed by the character 'X' for walls and '*' for walk-able cells. Maze entry is at top left and exit at bottom right.
I have implemented a breadth-first search, which is pretty slow, and a depth-first search which performs way better.

I heard that if I used A* and a good heuristic I could solve the maze faster. I tried to implement it but I am not sure that I am doing it right. Pseudocode for my algorithm so far :

```
    let s be a stack;
    for all nodes
      node.heuristic = INT_MAX;
    headnode.heuristic = 0;
    push head_node in stack;
    While (stack != empty)
    {
      current_node = pop_stack(s);
      if (current_node == goal_node)
        return (SUCCESS);
      for each node adjacent to current_node
        node.heuristic = Manhattan distance from goal node
      push edges in stack, starting by higher heuristic value;
     }
```

I compute the Manhattan distance heuristic  this way :
md = abs(goal.x - node.x) + abs(goal.y - node.y).

As you can see, my A* is basically the same as an iterative DFS, except for the heuristic part. 
I should probably mention that this algorithm is finding its way out in a reasonable amount of time, but is slightly slower than my DFS.
If anyone could give me a hand here, that would be great, as I am really struggling to implement an A* that performs better than my DFS.

Comment: Can you walk diagonally? Or just left/right/up/down?

Comment: This isn't A*. In A*, you don't pull items off the stack in the reverse order you pushed them -- you pull the item off which has the smallest `f(n) + h(n)` where `f(n)` is the cost to that node, and `h(n)` is the (admissable) heuristic.

Comment: @TejashDesai : I can only go up/down/left/right

Comment: @PaulHankin : Sorry, I am not sure I understand exactly what you mean, can you be more explicit please? I should just push all the edges and then pull the lowest distance + heuristic node?

Comment: Have you got a pseudocode description of A*? How does your code relate to that? Maybe you think that A* means any search algorithm that uses a heuristic and so "basically the same as an iterative DFS, except for the heuristic part" means to you that you've implemented A*. But A* describes a particular method of exploring nodes -- and that method is not implemented by this code.

Comment: That is indeed what I thought

Comment: @PaulHankin is right. You need to extract the node that gives the minimum value of f+h. I can see you have an h(n), but your f(n) currently is equal to the number of steps it took to reach that point. So any step that you take in the right/down directions will get you closer to the goal by 2 units, irrespective of your move or position. That is the reason why it looks similar to DFS.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I understand much better now

Comment: My suggestion would be to read up on A* search and where it can be used. Its generally used in video games to find shortest path. Elsewise, you can improve your heuristic. Say, a cell connected by wall on 3 sides will have a value of -3. This will give you an idea about which move to make and which to avoid - which is a better heuristic

Comment: Hi guys, just to not confuse future readers, f(n) is NOT the cost to reach the node, but the evaluation function, which is f(n) = g(n) + h(n), and g(n) IS the cost to reach the node from the start.